# Linear Programming

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One cake requires $150$gm flour and $50$gm fat and other requires $75$gm flour and $75$ gm fat. Amara wants to make as many cakes as possible when $1.5$kg flour and $0.6$kg fat are available. How many of each kind should she make?

My Attempt:

Let $x$ be the number of cakes of the first kind and $y$ be the number of second kind.

First Case;:

$$2x+y\leq 20$$

Second case;:

$$2x+3y\leq 24$$..

But whats next?

Comment: Can you make 1.5 cakes? -1 cakes?

Comment: Where did you get the second inequality from? What would be an expression for the total number of cakes made?

Comment: # Element118, what do you mean? I can not understand.

Comment: # copper. hat. This much was the hint given by my teacher.

Comment: @Iaamuseruser Did the answer help ? Any questions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you first take the number from the exercise the constraints are

$150x+75y\leq 1500$

$50x+75y\leq 600$

The first constraint can be divided by 75 and the second constraint can be divided by 25. And we get your form of the constraints.

If we have no other information we can assume the two cakes have the same utility (consumer) or the same price. In this case the coefficients of x and y have to be equal at the objective function. Let´s take 1 as the coefficient for both cakes.

$\texttt{max} \ \ x+y$

And finally x and y have to be non-negative whole numbers. To make the calculation more simple we just say x and y have to be non-negative numbers.

$x,y \geq 0$

Your definition of x and y is fine.

**Remark**:

This problem has only 2 variables. Therefore it can be solved graphically.